# Generate Text Fields in-app for MindMapping app Swift/xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, text, mindmapping

I am currently programming a Mind Mapping app, where the app user can add textfields wherever they want to on a blank page. Is there a way to do something like that. An unprofessional way I came up with, would be adding a few hundred empty textfields to the ViewController, that the user can then fill in. However I am sure there is a better way. Would be nice if the user could tap on a "Add Text" button to generate a Text Field (just like in Microsoft Word) that can be moved around on the blank page. I really cannot think of any class that could solve such a task. Can anybody help?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create a text field programatically. In your ViewController file, you will need to create an instance of `UITextField`. For information on UITextField, check out [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/).

For example, on iOS, when a user touches the screen with one or more fingers, methods are called on the View Controller. When a user touches the screen, iOS calls `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` on the View Controller. In your case, you probably want `touchesEnded`, so that the field will not be added until the user lifts his/her finger. These methods pass a Set of `UITouch`'s. [UITouch Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/index.html)

Example View Controller code in Swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        print("Touch Ended")

        for touch in touches {

            let touchPoint = touch.locationInView(self.view)

            let fieldFrame = CGRect(x: touchPoint.x, y: touchPoint.y, width: 100, height: 30)

            let textField = UITextField(frame: fieldFrame)
            textField.placeholder = "Type Here"

            view.addSubview(textField)

        }
    }

}
```

You may already be aware of how to programmatically layout views, but…

This code finds the location of the touch and makes that location the textfield's origin. Here, I am simply setting the frame for the textField before adding it the view, hardcoding a width of 100 and height of 30. In practice, you may want to look into something like AutoLayout, particularly [NSLayoutConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/index.html), which allows for programmatic constraints that account for bounds changes.
You also may not want to add a text field for each touch if they touch the screen with multiple fingers at once.

This allows a field to be placed wherever the user touches. Alternatively, you could create a button to add a text field like you said and then just come up with a default location for the `UITextField` to be added instead of observing touches.

### Dragging a text field

To move the field when the user drags a text field, you will want to observe a touch, and check for a textfield at the touch, which is essentially [checking for a subview at a point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665842/determining-if-a-point-in-a-view-is-within-a-subviews-bounds#13665942).

Then, you can use `touchesMoved` to observe a drag and update the location of the textfield via AutoLayout or whatever procedure you decide to use.

### Gesture Recognizer's

As an alternative to `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded`, you can use gesture recognizers. See information on the different types of `UITapGestureRecognizer`'s from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/). These can be created by specifying a target and action method, then added to a view.
Example of creating a tap gesture recognizer and adding it to a UITextField stored in a variable called textfield.

```
let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("textFieldTapped:"))
textfield.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

Comment: You are an absolute genius! Thanks a lot for this extensive and understandable explanation. Unfortunately I can't yet upvote your comment (no rep), but I am stil very thankful :)

Comment: I really liked the idea but using touchesEnded made it very difficult to do other gesture actions, which is why i decided to use ?`UITapGestureRecognizer` to solve the task. (So I can also use `PinchGesture` later and especially because I hope it's easier to drag the textfields around with the `PanGesture`) Unfortunately, that didn't really work out haha. This is how I set up my ViewController; `override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        let tapGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "didTap:")` I don't really know what's wrong with it because until now it worked properly.

Comment: The error says; Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1` and happens right after successfully building the project.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in Xcode? Look for a blue mark next to one of the lines. If you see it, you can right-click and delete it. As for [UITapGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITapGestureRecognizer), you should read the documentation linked. Right now, "didTap:" should fire whenever the user taps anywhere. If you find Gesture recognizers useful, I'll update my answer for them. Also note it may be easier to set up a gesture recognizer in the storyboard.

Comment: Yes thank you very much, the breakpoint was the problem ;) The code for the UITapRecognizer worked actually. I know, that would be easier. But is there a way to add a UITapGestureRecognizer for an object that doesn't exist yet? Because usually I would manually add an object to the ViewController in the storyboard and then link a GestureRecognizer with that specific object. Objects that are added when using the app on my device won't react on the gestures. Cheers

Comment: After you have created the UITapGestureRecognizer programmatically, you can call `textfield.addGestureRecognizer(tapGR)`. Keep in mind that a single UITapGestureRecognizer can only be added to a single object at a time, so you will need to create a new one for each textfield if you want one on every textfield. The `target` you specify when you create one is just the class you want the message sent to.